# How do I fix hostname resolution on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu Docker 16.04 server?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean, resolve

I don't know what happened, but I lost all hostname resolution on my DO Ubuntu server. What do I need to look for? Searches on Ubuntu 16.04 aren't helping as those are all about NetworkManager which doesn't exist in their image.

```sh
gp@gpc-docker-sfo2:~$ telnet gitlab.com 443
telnet: could not resolve gitlab.com/443: Temporary failure in name resolution
gp@gpc-docker-sfo2:~$ nslookup www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Can I get an idea on where I need to look to figure this out? I know Ubuntu has been changing up resolv.conf usage. I don't know where to look on this image.

Worthy note: image is called "Ubuntu Docker 1.12.5 on 16.04." I always keep packages updated with `apt` and Docker 13.0 was recently released. I don't know if that's relevant, but I do know that's one thing that changed which may(?) affect things.

I didn't notice the resolv issue until a good week or so later.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it ... Well. I don't who it happened -- looks like something went amiss when I added IPv6 to this image (post-create) via the online portal.

I creating a new image (IPv6 on create) in attempts to replicate. I found two differences in the new image:

- It had IPv6 settings within `interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg`
- It didn't have `ubuntu-fan` files within the `if-[up/down].d/` directories

So, I added IPv6 settings and removed the `ubuntu-fan` files.

Rebooted the box, and we're back working!

Any idea what the `ubuntu-fan` files are for? Are they necessary?